# Sockets: connection failed, connection refused

Tags: c, sockets

I have a socket app written in c and I am executing on linux, but when I execute the server (./server), I  get the following error:

> connection failed, connection refused.

Here is the code:

server.c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT 8080

void error(char* message){
    perror(message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void handler_client(void){
}

int main(int argc , char **argv[]){
    int server_fd;
    int new_socket;
    int valread;

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello, I'm server";

    if((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0)) == 0){
        error("socket failed");
    }

    if(setsockopt(server_fd , SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT , &opt , sizeof(opt))){
        error("setsockertopt");
    }

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);

    if(bind(server_fd , (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address) ) < 0){
        error("bind failure");
    }

    if(listen(server_fd , 3) < 0){
        error("listen");
    }

    if((new_socket = accept(server_fd , (struct sockaddr *)&address , (socklen_t *)&addrlen)) < 0){
        error("accept");
    }

    valread = read( new_socket , buffer , 1024);
    printf(" message from client : %s \n",buffer);
    send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0);
    printf("Hello message sent \n");
    return 0;

 }
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DEFAULT_PORT  8080
#define BUFFER_SIZE  1024

void error(char* message){
    perror(message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc , char** argv){
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int sock = 0;
    int valread;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char message[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

    if((sock = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0)) < 0){
        error("Sockert Creation fails");
    }

    memset(&serv_addr , '0' , sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(DEFAULT_PORT);

    if(inet_pton(AF_INET , "127.0.0.1" , &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0){
        error("Invalid address / Address not supported");
    }

    if(connect(sock , (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr , sizeof(serv_addr) ) < 0){
        error("connection failed");
    }

    printf("enter your message : ");

    fgets(message , BUFFER_SIZE-1 , stdin);

    send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0);
    printf("Hello message sent\n");
    valread = read(sock , buffer , BUFFER_SIZE);
    printf("response from buffer : %s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code works without any changes for me. Are you running both client and server inside the same system (and did you start the server before starting the client)? Running on different systems will not work since you've explicitly specified 127.0.0.1 (i.e. the local host) as target.

Comment: My main system is Mac OS, but I have installed ubuntu on virtual machine, so can you help me, which target should I specify? thanks

Comment: I am running server.c first, but even that is not working! Any suggestion?

Comment: You need to run both server and client inside the same system, i.e. either both inside MacOS or both inside the Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Understand, I am running both inside UBUNTU Vm, but even then I am getting connection refused, I can't even start the server... does it have something to do with the port I am using?8080?

Comment: If you cannot start the server then something else is probably using the same port (what error do you get on server start - something like address in use?). In this case you need to change the port to  free one.

Comment: If I understande well the question you executed the `server` and got the error `error: connection failed, connection refused`. But the error message is printed in client. You probably has some clash in filenames - may be the server binary is overwritten by the client by mistake.

Answer (score 3):

A "connection refused" error means you are trying to connection to a server IP:port that is either:

1. not open for listening
2. has too many pending client connections in its backlog
3. blocked by a firewall/router/antivirus.

There is no way on the client side to differentiate which condition is causing the error.  All it can do is try again later, and give up after awhile.

Since your client is trying to connection to `127.0.0.1`, the client and server MUST be run on the same machine.  You will not be able to connect across machine boundaries, and that includes VM boundaries between host/client systems.

That being said, I see a number of mistakes in your code, but none that are causing the connection error.

Server side:

1. `socket()` returns -1 on error, not 0.

   ```
   //if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0){
   if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
   ```
2. you can't set multiple socket options at a time with `setsockopt()`, you must set them individually with separate calls to `setsockopt()`.

   ```
   //setsockopt(server_fd , SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt));
   setsockopt(server_fd , SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &opt, sizeof(opt));
   setsockopt(server_fd , SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt));
   ```

Client side:

1. you are filling `serv_addr` with `'0'` characters instead of `0` bytes.

   ```
   //memset(&serv_addr , '0' , sizeof(serv_addr));
   memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
   ```

On both sides, you are not doing any error handling on `send()`.  But more importantly, you are not including the message's null terminator in the send, so the peer has no way of knowing when the end of the message is reached.  TCP is a streaming transport, so you need to frame your messages in your data protocol.  Send the message's length before sending the message itself.  Or send a unique terminator after the message.  The peer can then read the length before reading the message, or read until the terminator is reached.

Both `send()` and `read()` return how many bytes were actually sent/received, which can be (and frequently is) fewer bytes than requested. You need to call them in a loop to make sure that you send/receive everything you are expecting.

Also, `read()` does not return a null-terminated string, but your use of `printf()` expects one. Check `valread` for error, and only if `read()` was successful then pass `valread` to `printf()` as an input parameter so it knows how much data is actually in the `buffer`:

```
printf("message from client : %.*s\n", valread, buffer);
```

```
printf("response from buffer : %.*s\n", valread, buffer);
```